# How do you access member functions of a class object from within a different class object that has been created in it?

Tags: c++, class, object, member

```
class Class1  //Would be object mClass1
{
public:
 void Function1()
 {
  a++;
 }
private:
 int a = 0;
 Class2 mClass2;
}
```

(Editing in a space here to clarify Class2 is not defined after Class1; they are in separate files.)

```
class Class2  //Would be object mClass2
{
public:
 Function2()
 {
  Function1();  // Would be from mClass1
 }
}
```

So Class1 creates an instance of a Class2 object, and that Class2 object has a member function that wants to access the "parent" object's member function, without using inheritance.

I don't know what I specifically need to search for to learn about this. Does it have to do with dereferencing a `new` pointer? Constructor type/initialization? Does it have a terminology? "Nested classes" bring up classes defined inside another class, which is not what this is.

Answer (score 0):

Without inheritance there is no way to get the 'parent class'. So instead you should just pass the function as a parameter, maybe in the constructor of class 2 if you use it multiple times. See for example: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. `Class2` is not known yet when you define `Class1`, so the `Class1::mClass2` data member cannot possibly be created. But this problem can be solved by defining `Class2` before `Class1`, and implementing `Class2::Function2()` outside the class and only after `Class1`.

As for calling `Function1()` inside `Function2()`, `Class2` needs to know the object on which to call `Function1()`. You could use a reference member for that that you initialize in the constructor:

```
// Forward-declaration of Class1 so that Class2 will be able to define
// references or pointers to Class1.
class Class1;

class Class2
{
public:
    // Constructor that requires a reference to our parent object.
    explicit Class2(Class1& parent)
        : parent_(parent)
    { }
    
    // Just declare the function. We need to implement it later, outside
    // this class definition because Class1 is not fully known yet and as
    // a result we can't have calls to Function1() because the compiler
    // doesn't know that function yet.
    void Function2();
    
private:
    // This is just a reference, so it works even if Class1 is not fully
    // known yet.
    Class1& parent_;
};

class Class1
{
public:
    void Function1() { /* ... */ }

private:
    int a = 0;
    Class2 mClass2{*this}; // Pass ourself as the parent object.
};

// Class1 is fully known now, so we can do calls to Function1().
inline void Class2::Function2()
{
    parent_.Function1();
}
```

This will work, but it has an important implication: it disables the assignment operator of `Class2`. This is probably what you want in this case, because two copies of `Class2` should probably not have the same `Class1` parent object.

However, I don't see why you need to do this. It complicates matters for no good reason. Why not simply pass the `Class1` object that `Function2()` should use as a function argument instead? So:

```
class Class1;

class Class2
{
public:
    void Function2(Class1& c1_obj);
};

class Class1
{
public:
    void Function1() { /* ... */ }

private:
    int a = 0;
    Class2 mClass2;
};

inline void Class2::Function2(Class1& c1_obj)
{
    c1_obj.Function1();
}
```

So whenever `Class1` needs to call `Class2::Function2()`, just pass `*this` to it. It's simpler and doesn't have the drawbacks of holding a reference or pointer to another object.

Comment: I get "unknown override specifier" @ `Class2 mClass2{*this};` , plus eight related errors after that. Maybe because I don't use inline. Is it necessary to?

Comment: @Wicky Works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/qMeWenjz9 And yes, `inline` is necessary for functions implemented in header files but outside the class. (Except function templates, those don't need `inline`.) If you implement the function in a `.cpp` file, then `inline` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

With canonic classes - no way to do this, because `Class2` is incomplete within `Class1` and if you declare `Class2` inside of `Class1` (as a nested class), it wouldn't have access to `Class1`, because `Class1` incomplete!

Looks like an unsolvable paradox? It is unsolvable in OOP land, but can be dodged just like Nikos had shown.  But the problem of undefined types in some cases can be resolved in C++ or similar concept-oriented languages by using CRTP - [Curiously recurring template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

If it is possible or not in your use-case and how complex it would be depending on what purpose you pursue. Here is an example of a paradoxical CRTP behavior - a member of base class is able to call a member of derived class:

```
#include <iostream>

template < class T>
class Base { 

public:
      template <class U>
      struct Accessor : public U {
           static void evoke_foo( T& obj)
           {
                 return  (obj.*(static_cast< void(T::*)() >(&Accessor::foo))) ();
           }
      };

      void evoke(  )
      {  
           Accessor<T>::evoke_foo( *static_cast<T*>(this) );
      }
};


class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
protected:
      void foo()  { std::cout << "Foo is called" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    Derived a;
    a.evoke();   // evoke belongs to base.
}
```

Now if we'd want to determine return type of `foo()` automatically here, this would become an insanely complex piece of code. Some problems like that are solved in implementations of standard namesake of `evoke` method.

Comment: *"no way to do this, because Class2 is incomplete within Class1"* It's actually simple. Just define `Class2` before `Class1` :-P (See my answer.)

Comment: @Nikos then it would not have access to `Class1` the way how OP had show. Predeclaration and separating definition of declaration works in some cases  (and that's common way to do it), but there are cases where it's not possible. The reference approach often wrapped into CRTP (std components do that, through with reference_wrapper and trait class)

Comment: Well, usually you always separate declaration and definition anyway. You declare your classes in `.h` files, and define the "heavy" functions in the `.cpp` file, and the "lighter" functions as `inline` at the very bottom of the `.h` file. This has been the most common method in C++ for a while now. Most people don't want to litter the class' API with function definitions.

Comment: @NicosC true, for the part that alternative wasn't well developed in most compilers, though that was problem for standard components and their header-only nature. Only C++20 kind of solved it (and added new problems) by introducing modules. ANd it wasn't clear what OP had in mind. in your version Class2  and Class1 are separate objects, it's not a flat object. In mine, Base is analog of Class2 and is subobject of Derived (Class1).